# Expressão lambda dá erro de conversão

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, expressões-lambda

Essa é minha linq com lambda:

```
public JsonResult CarregaDescricaoRede(string _tipo_rede, string _uf, string _cidade)
        {
            var resultado_rede_descricao = (from _pdv in db.PDV
                                            .Where(r => r.Tipo_PDV == _tipo_rede)
                                            select new { _pdv.Descricao, _pdv.UF, _pdv.Cidade }).ToList().Distinct().OrderBy(o => o.Descricao);

            if(_uf != "Todos")
            {
                resultado_rede_descricao = resultado_rede_descricao.Where(c => c.UF == _uf); ***==> Aqui dá o erro***
            }

            return Json(new { resultado_rede_descricao }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Esse é o erro:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Linq.IOrderedEnumerable<AnonymousType#1>'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Penso que o teu erro está em fazeres o `OrderBy` antes da condição.

Tenta:

```
var resultado_rede_descricao = (from _pdv in db.PDV
                                .Where(r => r.Tipo_PDV == _tipo_rede)
                                select new { _pdv.Descricao, _pdv.UF, _pdv.Cidade }).ToList().Distinct();

if(_uf != "Todos")
{
    resultado_rede_descricao = resultado_rede_descricao.Where(c => c.UF == _uf).OrderBy(o => o.Descricao); ***==> Aqui dá o erro***
}
```